# Not printing correctly when checking for condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a text file containing lines from a different file that satisfy a condition. Specifically, I am grabbing the source code for https://docs.python.org/3/library/ and I want to create a text file containing the names of the standard libraries only and nothing else.

The source code looks like this

```
<p>In addition to the standard library, there is a growing collection of
several thousand components (from individual programs and modules to
packages and entire application development frameworks), available from
the <a class="reference external" href="https://pypi.org">Python Package Index</a>.</p>
<div class="toctree-wrapper compound">
<ul>
<li class="toctree-l1"><a class="reference internal" href="intro.html">Introduction</a><ul>
<li class="toctree-l2"><a class="reference internal" href="intro.html#notes-on-availability">Notes on availability</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want only those lines that start with '<li class="toctree-':

```
<li class="toctree-l1"><a class="reference internal" href="intro.html">Introduction</a><ul>
<li class="toctree-l2"><a class="reference internal" href="intro.html#notes-on-availability">Notes on availability</a></li>
```

Here's my code:

```
import requests
python_learn='H:\\Downloads\\Programming\\Python'
                    
r = requests.get('https://docs.python.org/3/library/')
with open(python_learn+'\\'+'python_std_lib.txt', 'wb') as output_file2:
    for line in r:
        if line.startswith(b'<li class="toctree-'):
            output_file2.write(line)
```

But instead of getting each line on a separate line, I am getting one very long line that looks strange:

```
<li class="toctree-l2"><a class="reference internal" href="collections.html"><code class="xref py py-mod docutils literal notran<li class="toctree-l2"><a class="reference internal" href="urllib.request.html"><code class="xref py py-mod docutils literal not<li class="toctree-l2"><a class="reference internal" href="modulefinder.html"><code class="xref py py-mod docutils literal notra
```

It seems like there is an issue with EOL. So I tried this instead:

```
            output_file2.write(line+b'\n')
```

But then I get three lines instead of one and I know for sure there are way more than three lines in the webpage that start with '<li class="toctree-':

```
<li class="toctree-l2"><a class="reference internal" href="collections.html"><code class="xref py py-mod docutils literal notran
<li class="toctree-l2"><a class="reference internal" href="urllib.request.html"><code class="xref py py-mod docutils literal not
<li class="toctree-l2"><a class="reference internal" href="modulefinder.html"><code class="xref py py-mod docutils literal notra
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer doesn't use beautiful soup, only standard libraries.

```
import urllib.request
python_learn='H:\\Downloads\\Programming\\Python\\'

urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://docs.python.org/3/library/', python_learn + 'std_lib_src.txt')
with open(python_learn + 'std_lib.txt', 'w') as output_file2:
    r = open(python_learn + 'std_lib_src.txt', 'rb')
    for line in r:
        if line.startswith(b'<li class="toctree-'):
        line = re.match('.*"(.*)\.html.*', line.decode('utf-8')).group(1)    
        output_file2.write(line)
```

Edited to include code that will isolate the names of the standard libraries (a substring of the entire line), if that is what is desired instead of the entire line.

Answer (score 2):

It is due to how the HTML file is cut with the get method from requests. You can print your variable `line` to see how the line looks like. If you want to have the result line by line, you need to use the method `iter_lines()` on your `r`object :

```
import requests

python_learn='H:\\Downloads\\Programming\\Python'                    
r = requests.get('https://docs.python.org/3/library/')

with open(python_learn+'\\'+'python_std_lib.txt', 'wb') as output_file2:
    for line in r.iter_lines():
        if line.startswith(b'<li class="toctree-'):
            output_file2.write(line+ b'\n')
```

As you want to parse an HTML file, the best is to use the library BeautifulSoup like this :

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

python_learn='H:\\Downloads\\Programming\\Python'

                    
r = requests.get('https://docs.python.org/3/library/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
with open(python_learn+'\\'+'python_std_lib.txt', 'wb') as output_file2:
    for line in soup.find_all('li', attrs={"class":re.compile('^toctree-')}):
        output_file2.write(bytes(line.text, 'utf8'))
```

Comment: It worked. But from your answer, I understand that the issue arises from requests.get. So I copy/pasted the source code into a text file and used the rest of my own code and that gave me all the lines starting with 'li class'. So my new question is: how do I grab the source code of a webpage AS IS, just like copying and pasting with a mouse or keyboard?

Comment: I updated my answer. If you want to have the result line by line, you need to use the method `iter_lines()`